# Arithmetic mean numeric distribution from a combination of input values

Tags: math, mean, numerical-methods

I probably haven't expressed the question properly in the title, but I have a .NET application that allows a user to select one of 5 possible answers in response to 16 presented questions. Each (mutually exclusive) selectable answer has an integer score per question of 0, 25, 50, 75 or 100 and the total is calculated as an Average (I guess this is the same as an arithmetic mean). So, by answering each of the 16 questions with one each of these 5 possible answers gives an output score in the range 0 to 100. This all works fine in the actual application by the way. There are no dependencies between the 16 answers btw.

But what I want to find is the result numeric distribution of all possible answer combinations that a user *could* choose. Or rather the inverse question of 'which integers in the range 0 to 100 **cannot** result from any of the possible answer combinations?'

I'm hoping that a math guru here knows how to calculate this or better still has the actual answer.

Comment: You have not selected any programming languages in the tags (but you mention .NET). If this is a math question, SO is not the place to ask.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is _not_ about programming, but rather about [Mathematics.SE].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually looking for the distribution of outcomes but the values themselves.  I'll propose a simpler approach.

Assume the outcomes are enumerated as 0,1,2,3,4 instead of 100 scale.  Your 16 question unit will become a 16 digit sequence in base 5, and the total can be between 0 and 16*4=64.  All whole number values between 0 and 64 are possible.  The average will be between 0 and 4 (with increments 1/16).  Now, scaling back to 100, you'll get values between 0 and 400 with increments (25/16=1.5625).

Answer (score 0):

The sum can be any multiple of 25 from 0 to 16x100, hence the average any multiple of 25/16=1.5625 between 0 and 100.

Note that if the scores are *rounded* to the closest integer, the possible outcomes are

0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 48, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 66, 67, 69, 70, 72, 73, 75, 77, 78, 80, 81, 83, 84, 86, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 95, 97, 98, 100.